# golang gota top n rows

Tags: dataframe, go, gota

Im converting my project from Python to Golang but Im stuck in regards to using Gota as an equivalent to Pandas dataFrame.

In Pandas I used df.nlargest(20, ['Change']) to extract the top highest values from my data set but I can't seem to find an equivalent.

I can use the following to sort the data

```
sorted := valuesDf.Arrange(dataframe.RevSort("Change"))
```

but still, I need a way to select the top 20 rows of data because next I want to calculate the Mean average for this updated dataFrame.

Which I will use the .Mean() function to achieve this

Does anyone know of a way to select the top 20 rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no func in the same function. But you can create your own.

```
sorted := dataframe.Arrange(
    dataframe.Sort("Change"),
)
```

Here we sort by a field.

```
sub := sorted.Subset([]int{0, 20})
```

Now we get the top 20 from this sorted dataframe.